# Autoresponder emails go to Spam - Junk folder

Tags: email, spam

we are facing the problem that almost all the Autoresponder Emails we are sending from Nex Form by basixonline are delivered into the Spam or Junk folders of the recipients (yahoo, gmail, and others). How to fix it? I already setup SMTP and Checked the SPF, DKIM, and DMARC Records.

Comment: Have you checked the address you use in your email headers? Some address will be flagged as spam.